# R data.frame with 0 values

Tags: r

My pos_TAT data frame contains 7 rows but the last one appears only when I do summary because its value is 0.

```
summary(pos_TAT)
Delayed$position.type  Delayed$TAT   
            JF     :1
           S20     :1
           S40     :1
           S60     :1
      Specials     :1
           S70     :1   
         14-19     :0



pos_TAT
  Delayed$position.type Delayed$TAT
1                    JF    45.10965
2                   S20    44.37831
3                   S40    44.18750
4                   S60    45.40698
5              Specials    43.30079
6                   S70    42.44444
```

That poses problem if I want to add a column with the count for example as it tells me there's a different number of rows 6, 7.

I've spent hours looking into that problem but can't find the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data as it will give us the structure of the data

Comment: What is the output of levels(pos_TAT$Delayed$position.type)?   Most likely it will display the 7 levels in your list.  Use the `droplevels` function to remove the used levels.

Comment: It seems very likely that you do not have seven rows (as suggested by akrun's guess below). Try typing `??"number of rows"` to see how to properly find out the number of rows...

Answer (score 2):

This could be possible when there are unused levels for `factor` columns in the dataset.  Either convert the column to `character` or if we need to keep it as `factor` class, then use `droplevels` or call `factor` again.

```
df2 <- droplevels(pos_TAT)
```

Or

```
df2 <- transform(pos_TAT, Delayed$position.type= as.character(Delayed$position.type))
```

---

The `summary` would also give the unused levels as the OP showed

```
summary(pos_TAT[1])
# Delayed$position.type
# JF      :1           
# S20     :1           
# S40     :1           
# S60     :1           
# Specials:1           
# S70     :1           
# 14-19   :0
```

#### data

```
pos_TAT <- structure(list(`Delayed$position.type` = structure(1:6, .Label = c("JF", 
"S20", "S40", "S60", "Specials", "S70", "14-19"), class = "factor"), 
Delayed.TAT = c(45.10965, 44.37831, 44.1875, 45.40698, 43.30079, 
42.44444)), .Names = c("Delayed$position.type", "Delayed.TAT"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank guys! Couldn't get it to work but I changed my levels and made groups where the 0 case doesn't exist. I need to go back to learning the basics.